# Configuring collection of polymorphic objects to work in JAXB2

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I'm switching from Castor to JAXB2 to perform marshaling/unmarshaling between XML and Java object. I'm having problem trying to configure a collection of polymorphic objects.

**Sample XML**

```
<project name="test project">
    <orange name="fruit orange" orangeKey="100" />
    <apple name="fruit apple" appleKey="200" />
    <orange name="fruit orange again" orangeKey="500" />
</project>
```

**Project class**

The `oranges` list works fine, I'm seeing 2 oranges in the list. But, I'm not sure how to configure `fruitList`. The `fruitList` should have 3 fruit: 2 oranges and 1 apple.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Project {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String          name;

    @XmlElement(name = "orange")
    private List<Orange>    oranges     = new ArrayList<Orange>();

    // Not sure how to configure this... help!
    private List<Fruit>     fruitList   = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
}
```

**Fruit class**

Fruit is an abstract class. For some reason, defining this class as an abstract seems to be causing a lot of problems.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class Fruit {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String  name;
}
```

**Orange class**

```
public class Orange extends Fruit {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String  orangeKey;
}
```

**Apple class**

```
public class Apple extends Fruit {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String  appleKey;
}
```

How do I configure my `fruitList` in `Project` to achieve what I want here?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to leverage @XmlElementRef this is corresponds to the XML schema concept of substitution groups which corresponds to your question.

**Step 1 - Using @XmlElementRef**

The fruitList property is annotated with @XmlElementRef:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Project {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlElementRef
    private List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

}
```

**Step 2 - Annotate Apple and Orange with @XmlRootElement**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Apple extends Fruit {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String  appleKey;

}
```

and

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Orange extends Fruit {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String  orangeKey;

}
```

**Demo Code**

The following code can be used to demonstrate the solution:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Project.class, Apple.class, Orange.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Project project = (Project) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(project, System.out);
    }

}
```

**For More Information:**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

Comment: I'm trying out your approach... I annotated the `fruitList` property with `@XmlElementRef` and annotated `Orange` and `Apple` classes with `@XmlRootElement`. I ran the code, and the `fruitList` came out empty. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: I figured out the problem, I have to add `Orange.class` and `Apple.class` into `JAXBContext.newInstance(..)` together with `Project`. Works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After futzing around... I think I got it working now:-

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Project {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String      name;

    // this has to be commented out, or else oranges won't show up in fruitList
    // @XmlElement(name = "orange")
    // private List<Orange> oranges = new ArrayList<Orange>();

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "orange", type = Orange.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "apple", type = Apple.class)
    })
    private List<Fruit> fruitList   = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

}
```

Comment: @XmlElements will work, but each time you add a new subclass you will have to edit the Project class.  If you use @XmlElementRef instead you will just need to annotate the new subclass with @XmlRootElement.  @XmlElements is more for representing choice structures:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html

Answer (score 0):

Put XmlAnyElement annotation:

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
private List<Fruit>     fruitList   = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
```

Comment: That didn't work... `fruitList` contains one `apple` of type `ElementNSImpl`.

Comment: For @XmlAnyElement you would need to add @XmlRootElement to each of the subclasses.  This is meant more for wild card sections though.  Since the child objects are in an inheritance relationship @XmlElementRef is a better choice here.  For more info on @XmlAnyElement see:http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html